Failed to initialize GTK when loading a window using Vulkan
I'm on an Arch Linux machine. I have a program that is using Vulkan and should load a window. It is loading, but it only shows up in the bottom toolbar and won't display the window itself.
The error says: "Failed to initialize GTK, Failed to load plugin libdecor-gtk.so".
The GTK package is up to date and the plugin is in the GTK-3/modules dir.

Vulkan support is a function of your video card and driver.  The open source Linux drivers may not support Vulkan yet.
